# How could I separate a multiple delimited values and store them to a separate variable?

Tags: python, arrays

The Data that I have is like :

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,~9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,~17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,~GV=15,ld=34,gain=15,c=12,ld=45,bpm=12,#*#31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,~39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,~47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,~GV=15,ld=34,gain=15,c=12,ld=100,bpm=130]
```

I need them to be separated like:

```
B = [
    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,
    9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,
    17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,
    31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,
    39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,
    47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54
]

C = [
    GV=15,ld=34,gain=15,c=12,ld=45,bpm=12
    GV=15,ld=34,gain=15,c=12,ld=100,bpm=130
]
```

What should I do to get an output like this in python?!

Comment: Are these all strings?

Comment: First, you have to explain to us your logic. Where does B start? Ditto for C.

Comment: A is a string, B and C can in a list or array.

Comment: let me put it together, A is a Raw data, a string. it consists of many delimiters. I need to split it up and save those numbers alone into a single array or list and those character things into another array or list.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel- I can't get the question clearly. As for now B and C is the output that I need to be separated from A.

Comment: @narashimhaakannan does B and C contains all items of type string?

Comment: @narashimhaakannan The code in your question isn't valid python. Please edit it so that it shows some **real** input and output values. Don't keep forcing people to guess what you mean.

Comment: @ekhumoro- thank you for your interest. Am new to this site. The thing over there up are some data. They are not sample code. A is the data I have. C and B are the output I need. Am learning python. I came here to get some ideas.

Comment: @Ava- B and C are the output that I need from A. B and C can be of any type. Sorry If didn't make u clear earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
A_str = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,~9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,~17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,~GV=15,ld=34,gain=15,c=12,ld=45,bpm=12,#*#31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,~39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,~47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,~GV=15,ld=34,gain=15,c=12,ld=100,bpm=130"
A = A_str.split(',')
new_A = []

for elem in A:
    if elem[0] == '~':
        new_A.append(elem[1:])
    elif len(elem) > 3 and elem[0:3] == "#*#":
        new_A.append(elem[3:])
    else:
        new_A.append(elem)

A = new_A
B = []
C = []

for elem in A:
    try:
        B.append(int(elem))
    except ValueError:
        C.append(elem)

print(B)
print(C)
```

Comment: @Octavel- In A all the elements are string.

Comment: @narashimhaakannan Then this code should work

Comment: But It shows invalid syntax.. at that "except ValueError:"

Comment: @narashimhaakannan My bad, I corrected it and improved upon it.

Comment: @OctaveL- Thanks, it really helped. Now it worked out.

Comment: @OctaveL-By the way is there any method to store the values of B in an array format with 8 column .

Comment: @narashimhaakannan What do you mean, 8 columns?

Comment: yeah separating the values by 8 each in an array and storing it to an variable

Answer (score 0):

You can use python list comprehension for pulling out the elements that match your pattern. I don't exactly know what your pattern is, but it looks like if it has an "=" you'd like to assign it to C, otherwise you'd like to assign it to B. Additionally, you have cleaned some other characters. I'm going to assume you don't care about data types and are happy to have lists of strings.

```
# you'll need the re library to help you clean up the data
import re

# store your data as a string
A = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,~9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,~17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,~GV=15,ld=34,gain=15,c=12,ld=45,bpm=12,#*#31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,~39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,~47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,~GV=15,ld=34,gain=15,c=12,ld=100,bpm=130"

# convert to a list
x = A.split(",")

# create B output based on elements that don't have "=" and keep only the numbers
B = [re.search(r'[0-9]+', i).group(0) for i in x if "=" not in i]
# ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '50', '51', '52', '53', '54']

# create C output based on elements that have "=" and remove "~"
C = [i.replace("~","") for i in x if "=" in i]
# ['GV=15', 'ld=34', 'gain=15', 'c=12', 'ld=45', 'bpm=12', 'GV=15', 'ld=34', 'gain=15', 'c=12', 'ld=100', 'bpm=130']
```

edit: of course, if you do care about data types you can intergerise those strings pretty safely. C has to be strings really.

```
B = [int(re.search(r'[0-9]+', i).group(0)) for i in x if "=" not in i]
#[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54]
```

edit2: The data structures you've illustrated in the question are not something that exist in python but it looks like a list of lists. So this would be the solution where you want lists of lists where we include the delimiters "~" and "#*#"

```
import re

# store your data as a string
A = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,~9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,~17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,~GV=15,ld=34,gain=15,c=12,ld=45,bpm=12,#*#31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,~39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,~47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,~GV=15,ld=34,gain=15,c=12,ld=100,bpm=130"
# convert to a list
x = re.split('~|#\*#', A)

B = [ list(filter(None, i.split(","))) for i in x if  "=" not in i]
C = [list(filter(None, i.split(","))) for i in x if  "=" in i]

print(B)
#[['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'], ['9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16'], ['17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24'], ['31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38'], ['39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46'], ['47', '48', '49', '50', '51', '52', '53', '54']]
print(C)
#[['GV=15', 'ld=34', 'gain=15', 'c=12', 'ld=45', 'bpm=12'], ['GV=15', 'ld=34', 'gain=15', 'c=12', 'ld=100', 'bpm=130']]
```

Comment: @jamesh- the data that I have posted is a part of my data. My data has nearly 10,000 values. These characters occurs many times as many occurance with different value. How could I seperate all the occurrence.

Comment: ah I see, "~" and "#*#" are also separators?

Comment: Yup, ~ #*# are all seperators

Comment: Your code really helped @jamesh. Thanks a lot.